# the difference between expense or cost?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between expense and cost ?  what is the phrase to describe all the cost for one person in one day?

Comment: Perhaps 'per diem' ('per day') is the phrase you're looking for.

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. Best to post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

An 'expense' is made or possessed by a subject, usually a person or group.

Example:

*The team's* total **expenses** for the week are (xyz).

A 'cost' is a quality held by a subject, usually an item or set of items.

Example:

*The item's* total **cost** is (xyz).

Hope this helps.